# Powershell filter a list of names

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Heyho, for a little script I'm making I have a huge list of users that I get from the active directory,
for example by:

```
$userlist = Get-ADUser -Filter *
```

I've already narrowed it down to the search only the folder that I want it to search.. but there are still some "corpses" in there, some dead accounts that don't need to be in the list, but that also can't be deleted from the domain. How can I filter these accounts out of the list?
Here are the fields that each user has in my list:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABgG8.png) of the output from Get-ADUser

If possible I'd like to filter out a list of names that are in another text file that I put into a variable. (I'd like to filter it by the "Name" field)

I've tried things along the line of:

```
$userlist = Get-AdUser -Filter 'Name -notin $Filter'
```

but that doesn't seem to work :(
I managed to do it with a single keyword, but can't get it done with a list

```
$userlist = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -notlike "*test*"'
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Active Directory Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)) doesn't support the `-notin` operator. You can use the following LDAP Filter trick to exclude those users from your query:

```
# $toExclude could be also pulled from a file, however you need to make
# sure there are no trailling or leading spaces on each line,
# you can use `.Trim()` for that.
#
# $toExclude = (Get-Content userstoexclude.txt).ForEach('Trim')

$toExclude = 'user.example1', 'user.example2', 'user.example3'
$filter = '(&(!name={0}))' -f ($toExclude -join ')(!name=')
# LDAP Filter would look like this:
# (&(!name=user.example1)(!name=user.example2)(!name=user.example3))

$userList = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filter
```

If you're interested in learning more about LDAP Syntax for your queries you might want to check out:

- [Active Directory: LDAP Syntax Filters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx)

Comment: you can even use wildcards in your name `test*`, `*test*`....

Comment: thanks this worked! I pulled the names from the textfile and they got filtered out, though I have close to no idea what all the symbols in $filter do though, guess I'll check out the link you posted, thanks!

Comment: @CFou yes you can however in this case, as far as I understood, OP has an exact list of users that need to be excluded. Adding wildcards to the search would make the query inefficient and you would also bring users that might not be to be excluded.

Comment: @realjapaner84 my pleasure, happy to help. I definitely recommend you to check out that link, it will be very useful when working with AD :)